# Can I prevent scriptreplay from losing cursor positioning?

Tags: bash, cursor

I'm using **script** and **scriptreplay** without anything fancy in the way of options:

```bash
script -T timecodes
...
exit
scriptreplay -t timecodes
```

On playback, things start out well, tracking my keyboard shortcuts (`Ctrl-A`, `Esc B`, `Ctrl-W`, arrow keys, etc), correctly deleting words and recalling previous commands. It appears to do okay with full-terminal window apps like **emacs** and the **most** pager.

But at some point the cursor positioning goes awry, and the user's typing starts happening in the wrong place, overwriting text that should not be overwritten. I *think* it may be related to very long lines that wrap. The other possibility that occurs to me is that it may be related to playing back in a terminal window of different dimensions than the window in which it was recorded.

Are there ways to eliminate the problem? (I'm wanting to use **script** and **scriptreplay** as teaching tools, and be able to send the files via e-mail for others to replay.)

Related: I see there's stuff about *logging-format* and *log-timing* (as well as *log-io*, *log-in*, and *log-out*) but I'm not finding the man page particularly clear on the possible benefits. Would any of those help with the problem?